# my android program code not started and show a massage "Unfortunately, "projectname" has stopped"

Tags: android, eclipse

my android program code not started and show a massage "Unfortunately, "projectname" has stopped"

I'm just writing my first program with android eclipse but it seems that have an error inside java code. could any one tell me what's the error??

```
 package com.example.first;

 import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private Button plus,minus ;
private TextView number;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    plus= (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
    minus=(Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);
    number= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    plus.setOnClickListener(this);
    minus.setOnClickListener(this);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onClick(View v)
{
    if(v.getId() ==  R.id.plus)
    {
        number.setText("Plus");
    }

    else if(v.getId() ==  R.id.minus)
    {
        number.setText("Minus");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: access Views after setting layout for Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Move these to the starting of the OnCreate your app will start working

Answer (score 0):

Make your onCreate method like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

plus= (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
minus=(Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);
number= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
...
```